# What does "ValueError: When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect the tensors to have a static batch size" mean?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I am using keras to build a neural network for predicting diabetes. However I encountered a ValueError: When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect the tensors to have a static batch size.

I tried changing the input shapes but I am still stuck.

```
num_classes = 2
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model

# This returns a tensor
inputs = Input(shape=(784,))

# a layer instance is callable on a tensor, and returns a tensor
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(x)

# This creates a model that includes
# the Input layer and three Dense layers
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x,y)  # starts training
```

After running
ValueError: When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect the tensors to have a static batch size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of these lines `x` is a Layer object

```
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
```

The model should be fitted on actual data but instead you pass in a Layer object:

```
model.fit(x,y)  # starts training
```

To simply put it your `x`, which is a `Layer` object, is a symbolic tensor and keras tries to treat it as a data tensor but fails.

To fix this just make sure that the `x` that you're passing in is indeed your `x` training data.

Comment: I used sklearn to split my data. How would that affect what my code should be?

Comment: It doesn't affect the code at all. Just `fit` your data on the actual `x` and not a random layer. Either change the name of the layer or change the name of the data.

Comment: Just like @Primusa said. fit the truely x_train data.

Answer (score 0):

Because x is not the training data when you feed the model (x,y), I fix your code as following:

```
model.fit(x_train,y_train)  # starts training
```